# Pagination in hiding some based on the result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the pagination but it displays all of the result.  I want to hide some.

Been trying to adjust it but no good result.

```
$Num_Rows = mysqli_num_rows($objQuery);

$Per_Page = 10;   // Per Page

$Page = $_GET["Page"];
if (!$_GET["Page"]) {
    $Page = 1;
}

$Prev_Page = $Page - 1;
$Next_Page = $Page + 1;

$Page_Start = (($Per_Page * $Page) - $Per_Page);
if ($Num_Rows <= $Per_Page) {
    $Num_Pages = 1;
} else if (($Num_Rows % $Per_Page) == 0) {
    $Num_Pages = ($Num_Rows / $Per_Page);
} else {
    $Num_Pages = ($Num_Rows / $Per_Page) + 1;
    $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
}


$strSQL .= " order  by lName ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
$objQuery = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
```

Comment: I don't see how this code would result in an incorrect query, since it looks like there is *always* the limit of 10 rows in it. Then again, not everything is here. I think your best bet would be to `var_dump($strSQL)` just before you execute it, to see what the actual query is. An accidental semicolon could already cause this, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code;

```
$query = "YOUR QUERY HERE";

$perPage = 10;
$page = isset($_GET["Page"]) ? $_GET["Page"] : 1;

$offset = ($page - 1) * $perPage;

$strSQL = $query." ORDER BY lName ASC LIMIT $offset , $perPage";
$objQuery = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this code is cleaner than OP's, but I'm not convinced by the usefulness of this answer. The code that OP shows to calculate Page_Start/offset should give the same result, but instead they gets every row, leading to the belief that there is another issue somewhere else. Replacing their chunk of code with yours isn't going to fix that.